# Separate logic from ui component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in react and I have an abstract question. Imagine that I have a button component without any logic. I have 2 tasks. 1) I have to add the product to the cart on click 2) I have to submit the form on click.
My question is can I somehow add logic without modification
button component?
Taking the component as a basis, make a new one and add the logic that I need?

I tried wrapping the component and doing something but still going back to adding a new prop to my ui component

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this by adding an `onClick` prop to the button component and then passing it to the `<button />` element in the jsx. While creating UI components it is better to pass all props to the wrapped element and override the style properties. Refer to the below example.

```
const CustomUIButton = (props) => <button className="custom-css" style={customStyle} {...props} />
const customStyle = {};
```

This way you are letting the user override the existing styles as well.

I hope I have answered your question.